# "vector iterator not incrementable" run-time error with set_intersection

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

Why does this code result in a run-time error "vector iterator not incrementable"?

```
vector<string> s1, s2;

 s1.push_back("joe");
 s1.push_back("steve");
 s1.push_back("jill");
 s1.push_back("svetlana");

 s2.push_back("bob");
 s2.push_back("james");
 s2.push_back("jill");
 s2.push_back("barbara");
 s2.push_back("steve");

 sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
 sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());

 vector<string> result;
 vector<string>::iterator it_end, it_begin;
 it_end = set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), result.begin());
 cout << int (it_end - result.begin()) << endl;
 for_each(result.begin(), result.end(), print);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`result.begin()` of an empty vector is not a valid output iterator. You need a  [`back_inserter(result)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) instead.

```
#include <iterator>
...
set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), back_inserter(result));
cout << result.size() << endl;
```

Alternatively, resize `result` to at least 4, so that the vector can contain all results.

Comment: Interestingly, this does not compile for me.  I use `back_inserter` all the time, and I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: Without knowing the error, do you miss the `<iterator>` include?

Comment: How would you modify this to use set instead of vector?

Comment: @Mark: Nope, maybe I'll put up a new post.

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is.  OP was trying to assign the results of `set_intersection` to a `vector<string>::iterator`, rather than a `back_insert_iterator<vector<string> >`

Comment: And Kenny's solution didn't keep the return value from `set_intersection`

Comment: @KennyTM: Additional +1 for the link to ideone.com :)

Comment: @myself - replace back_inserter with inserter(set, set.begin()) to put output into a set rather than a vector

Comment: Same problem and solution for string