# list/vector iterator not incrementable

Tags: c++, list, vector

So I have an issue trying to iterate through my container in c++ with visual studio Community 2015.
I'm trying to write a server/client on windows using select() and I get the error:

> vector iterator not incrementable

I'm not calling a vector::erase() or such, although I do use a vector::push_back()

```
void MGKServer::mainLoop()
{
    MGKServerSocket *mgk;
    std::vector<User *> users;
    int             actual = 0;
    char            buffer[1024];

    mgk = new WindowsServerSocket();
    mgk->init("127.0.0.1", 4242, "TCP");

    int             sock = mgk->getSock();
    std::cout << "sock is: " << mgk->getSock() << std::endl;
    while (1)
    {
        this->setFd(sock, &users); // FD_ZERO(&_readfd) and FD_SET for each user's socket and the server socket
        std::cout << "there is currently " << users.size() << " user(s) connected" << std::endl;
        if (select(FD_SETSIZE + 1, &this->_readfd, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
            exit(errno);
        // When a user connects
        if (FD_ISSET(sock, &this->_readfd))
        {
            // addNewUser creates a pointer to an object User , set his socket to the given one and push it in the vector
            if (this->addNewUser(sock, &users) == -1)
                std::cout << "Can't add newUser" << std::endl; 
        }
        // When a user sends a message to the server
        else
        {
            int debug = 0;
            std::vector<User *>::iterator   it = users.begin();
            while (it != users.end())
            {
                if (it == users.end())
                    std::cout << "Test if something went wrong with iterations" << std::endl;
                if (FD_ISSET((*it)->getSocket(), &this->_readfd))
                {
                    // RecvUser will just call recv with the client socket and store the message in buffer.
                    int c = mgk->recvUser((*it)->getSocket(), buffer);
                    // Means the user disconnected so i close his socket
                    if (c == 0)
                    {
                        std::cout << "user with socket: " << (*it)->getSocket() << "disconnected" << std::endl;
                        closesocket((*it)->getSocket());
                    }
                    // Means he sends an instruction
                    else
                        std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
                }
                std::cout << "Debug = " << debug << std::endl;
                ++debug;
                it++; // <- This small line seems to be the problem
            }
            std::cout << "Out of For loop" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "found something on socket" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

here is what i do in addNewUser:

```
int     MGKServer::addNewUser(int socket, std::vector<User *> *users)
{
    std::cout << "----NEW USER----" << std::endl;
    SOCKADDR_IN usin = { 0 };
    User        *u;
    int         size;
    int         usock;

    size = sizeof(usin);
    std::cout << "New user is trying to connect, socket is: ";
    usock = accept(socket, (SOCKADDR *)&usin, &size);
    if (usock == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "socket error occured" << std::endl;
        return (-1);
    }
    std::cout << usock << std::endl;
    FD_SET(usock, &this->_readfd);
    u = new User();
    u->setSocket(usock);
    users->push_back(u);
    return (0);
}
```

My object User only contains a socket with get&set methods for now.
My MGKServerSocket is just an abstration for windows/linux socket. It contain basic function for initializing my socket and send & recv data to users.

---

So at first I had a list container but I've got the same error. So I switched to try with vector instead but nothing changed.
In the beginning, I also used a for loop instead of my current while loop but, once again, nothing changed.

---

I know that there's already many questions for this error, but they usually use [erase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426959/vector-iterator-not-incrementable), [insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506605/c-vector-iterator-not-incrementable-error) inside the for loop or [create the iterator when the list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477955/vector-iterator-not-incrementable-run-time-error-with-set-intersection) which I don't. **So my question is, why do I get this error ?**

Comment: `vector::push_back` can invalidate iterators (it alway invalidates end iterator and will invalidate others if internal storage was reallocated)

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot But `vector::push_back` is used outside the while loop, my iterator is created after the push_back. I have an If/else to be sure that they aren't executed in the same loop "turn". Are you certain it's from the push_back ?

Comment: My guess is that the error is somewhere else. I would replace the use of the iterator with a `for(User* pUser : users)`. Then use `pUser` everywhere you have `*it`. If pUser becomes garbage at some point, you know something is stepping on memory. Perhaps running under valgrind would help? Or if on windows try using gflags.

Comment: Since you are using VS2015, have you tried breaking into debugger? You can walk up the call stack and it will even tell you what values the variables were when this happened.

Comment: @Xarn I tried to add a breakpoint, but since it is a runtime error there is nothing really helpfull from the debugger

Comment: Try roughly this: Set your Platform to x64 and Configuration to Debug. (Assuming default layout, its at the top of the window, mildly to the left) Then run the program from the visual studio and let it crash. Once it reports the error, you should be given option to abort/retry/ignore (or something very similar) with a note that to debug the error you need to pick retry. Pick retry, then break and you should be at the failure site. At the bottom right you should have a call stack tab. Pick it and click at some line in your code. At this point, you should be at the callsite that caused error

Comment: and you should be able to just look at the program state in the place of failure.